# AWS CLI S3API find newest folder in path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I've got a very large bucket (hundreds of thousands of objects). I've got a path (lets say s3://myBucket/path1/path2). /path2 gets uploads that are also folders. So a sample might look like:

```
s3://myBucket/path1/path2/v6.1.0
s3://myBucket/path1/path2/v6.1.1
s3://myBucket/path1/path2/v6.1.102
s3://myBucket/path1/path2/v6.1.2
s3://myBucket/path1/path2/v6.1.25
s3://myBucket/path1/path2/v6.1.99
```

S3 doesn't take into account version number sorting (which makes sense) but alphabetically the last in the list is not the last uploaded. In that example .../v6.1.102 is the newest.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
aws s3api list-objects 
--bucket myBucket
--query "sort_by(Contents[?contains(Key, \`path1/path2\`)],&LastModified)"´ 
--max-items 20000
```

So one problem here is max-items seems to start alphabetically from the all files recursively in the bucket. 20000 does get to my files but it's a pretty slow process to go through that many files.

So my questions are twofold:

1 - This is still searching the whole bucket but I just want to narrow it down to path2/ . Can I do this?

2 - This lists just objects, is it possible to pull up just a path list instead?

Basically the end goal is I just want a command to return the newest folder name like 'v6.1.102' from the example above.

Comment: use `head-object`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To answer #1, you could add the `--prefix path1/path2` to limit what you're querying in the bucket.

In terms of sorting by last modified, I can only think of using an SDK to combine the [`list_objects_v2`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) and [`head_object`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object) (boto3) to get last modified on the objects and programmatically sort

**Update**

Alternatively, you could reverse sort by `LastModified` in [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/specification.html) and return the first item to give you the most recent object and gather the directory from there.

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 \
--bucket myBucket \
--prefix path1/path2 \
--query 'reverse(sort_by(Contents,&LastModified))[0]'
```

Comment: Thanks! Prefix definitely works for narrowing, I'm getting syntax errors for reverse: Unknown function: reverse but I can probably figure it out from here.

Comment: Perhaps your `awscli` is out of date? I did this using version 1.11.183. `pip install -U awscli`

Comment: Oh, there it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want general purpose querying e.g. "lowest version", "highest version", "all v6.x versions" then consider maintaining a separate database with the version numbers.

If you only need to know the highest version number and you need that to be retrieved quickly (quicker than a list object call) then you could maintain that version number independently. For example, you could use a Lambda function that responds to objects being uploaded to path1/path2 where the Lambda function is responsible for storing the highest version number that it has seen into a file at s3://mybucket/version.max.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix works with list_object using boto3 client. But using boto3 resource might give some issues. Paginator in pagination is a great concept and works nice!. to find the latest changes(additions of objects) : sort_by(contents)[-1]